# i want change language according to access point

Tags: currency, multicurrency, currency-rates, country-regions, countries

hi i want to change language according to country visitors means if any user access my website in us than price show in dollar and another access in india than price shows in INR. please help me how can i do

Answer (score 0):

You can try some of the extensions that are available in the market or You may try GeoIP to get the location of the customer and then you can change language/currency using your code based on the location. 
You may try this one too:
https://xmagestore.com/magento2/geoip-extension.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please note that whenever you link to your own website, you must explicitly state so; see the [help center](/help/promotion).

Comment: ok but this extension is paid

Comment: and are you sure this will be working

Comment: yes it will work.